# Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send mail through PHP Mailer. Once i click on submit getting this error,

> Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

I googled it but couldn't find the right answer which will help me solving this. Please help me experts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my sample at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338535/cant-get-phpmailer-working/37338622#37338622 Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply but files are uploaded on server.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests you're sending using the default transport, which uses PHP's `mail()` function, which in turn requires that you have a `sendmail` binary installed on your local machine. If you don't have one, it can't work and will give you this error. Alternatively you may have one installed but in a different location, in which case you ned to update your php.ini file to point at it (see `sendmail_path`) You need to either install a mail server such as postfix, or switch to the SMTP transport and use a remote server.

Comment: its working on my friend's hosting but its not working on the host which im using, its one of my client's hosting.. What seems to be the issue i have failed to understand.. And im new to this things.. Is there anything related to the permission from hosts provider.